# I failed to notify ward office of fixed residence within 14 days. What will happen?

Tags: working-visas, residence-cards, japan

I arrived in Japan on August 2 and now it's October 15. I'm on an Engineer visa (5 years) and I'm working in Japan. It's the first time I entered Japan for work.

I failed to give notice to my local ward about my residence address, the one that you have to notify within 14 days. According to the Ministry of Justice's website, my residence status could be revoked... I plan to go to the ward office tomorrow.

In theory, I could be charged for a fine up to 200,000 yens, am I right? I just wanted to know how toasted I am. Has anyone experienced this?

Comment: Let us know tomorrow after your visit to the ward... Anything else here would only be speculation.

Comment: As long as you are overly apologetic and accept all blame yourself and say sorry as many times as you can, you *should* be ok. But the performance of contrition is critical.

Answer (score 4):

Hello everyone and thanks for your replies !

I went to the ward office right after and they just asked me why I didn't registered earlier within the 14 days. I just told that I simply was not aware of this 14 days procedure and they wrote it on some "comments" section on paper. As well, they were kind of repeating the same thing 2 times like "oh... since August...well". But nothing very offensive.

After that they registered my resident card, and wrote my address behind it as the normal procedure is.

I don't know if it has any kind of importance, but I speak japanese. So it could help.

And that's it. I was not charged for anything. But take care, it's maybe because I did not exceeded another internal and non shared deadline (my case is less than 90 days but more than 14 days).

So to sum up:
  - I just explained my situation and have been honest with it
  - I was not charged for anything
  - The procedure completed sucessfully and I got my resident record

If anyone come here for the same situation, I would advise:

**Do it right away and be honest with your situation. If possible speak japanese to simplify the communication.**

Answer (score 3):

Nothing will happen if you finally do it. But it's better to do it earlier.

I did not notify them about a new job because I was told the employer does it. When I went the following year to the Immigration bureau to extend my visa, they noticed that my current company did not match the registered one. But they just asked me to fill a job change form.

Comment: That's a very different thing.